# Not able to enter case-sensitive credential in android app

Tags: java, testng, appium, android-automation

I am writing a test case for an android app where the app requires case-sensitive credentials. I writing test cases using appium and TestNG.

Steps I am following are -

1. Launching app
2. Entering username and password e.g. username : user_test and password : User@123
3. Tapping on Login button.

**Result**

1. App launched successfully.
2. Entered wrong credentials username: user_test and password: USer@123

The problem here is that it's entering the wrong password. Two characters of a password in upper-case: **USer@123**.

The function I use to enter text in the password field is -

```
inspectElement(XpathConstants.PASS_TXT_XPATH).sendKeys("User@123");
```

Comment: So basically you are able to enter case-sensitive credentials but there is some issue with sending the proper keys?

Comment: Can you please check you have to test password with 2 letters in capital case- in your question "USer@123"  and in your script there is only one letter in capital case "User@123"

Comment: What it enters in password field right now?

Comment: I am entering "User@123", but its typing "USer@123". Yes, some issue with sending the proper keys? @Alexey

Comment: Try to invoke sendKeys for each particular symbol of your password.

Comment: I didn't heard previously about this scene with selenium and I don't think this is an bug in Selenium. You could check with your application behavior.

Try to run the same scenario on different Android/Appium version. 

Try with alternate ways of SendKeys like JavaScript Executor, Robot class etc.  Another option First click the Pawd field then wait for 2 Sec and use SendKeys

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking it down into three steps:

```
WebElement password = inspectElement(XpathConstants.PASS_TXT_XPATH);
password.clear();
password.sendKeys("User@123");
```

Comment: Tried but still same problem exists. Any other way ?

Comment: I've never seen the behavior you're describing before.  I would do a global search of my source code for "USer" (obviously case-sensitive search) to see if there is somehow some other code that is getting executed instead of the code you think is getting executed.  If all else fails, I would change the password to some other mixed case word and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Right, I tried the exact Scenario with my current Android version 4.4.2 and it works well..
I shocked with this crazy behavior.. Need to search more on this..

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else works, you can do the truly horrible workaround of adding a delay to each letter entered (this is assuming that the time to switch from upper-case to lower-case is what is causing your problem).

Your code would do something like this (no guarantees that the code is actually correct - it's a long time since I've worked with Java - but the principle is sound)

```
string password = "User@123";
char[] pwdArray = password.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < pwdArray.length(); i++) 
{
   passwordElement.sendKeys(pwdArray[i].toString());
   thread.sleep(5); // Adjust the sleep time until entry doesn't take too long but gives the correct result
}
```

Make no mistakes, this is a *horrible* way to fix this problem, but it may be the only way you can do it - especially if you are testing with different credentials.

Answer (score 0):

If sendKeys isn't working properly, to enter the password "User@123" with the correct case, you can use the following code:

```
String password = "User@123";
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(XpathConstants.PASS_TXT_XPATH)));
for (char c : password.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
        action.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).sendKeys(String.valueOf(c)).keyUp(Keys.SHIFT);
    } else {
        action.sendKeys(String.valueOf(c));
    }
}
action.build().perform();
```

This code uses the Actions class to simulate keyboard actions. The code loops through each character in the password string and checks if it is uppercase. If the character is uppercase, it presses the SHIFT key before entering the character. If the character is lowercase, it enters the character without pressing the SHIFT key.